# QGIS Field Calculator Expression - GeoHash32

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, geohash

I am attempting to write a QGIS 3.10 Field Calculator Expression that will use the mz2geohash library to encode the centroid of the current feature as LAT/LON, and then pass this tuple to the mz2geohash.encode() function to return a value.

I've in-lined my current code below, as well as linked to where it lives on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Saijin-Naib/QGIS-Processing-Models/blob/master/geohash32.py):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import mz2geohash

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def geohash32(value,feature,parent):
    ft_centroid = centroid($geometry)
    ft_lon = x(transform(ft_centroid),layer_property(@layer_id,'crs'),'EPSG:4326'))
    ft_lat = y(transform(ft_centroid),layer_property(@layer_id,'crs'),'EPSG:4326'))
    ft_array = []
    ft_array.append(ft_lon)
    ft_array.append(ft_lat)
    geohash32 = mz2geohash.encode
    return geohash32(ft_array)
```

**Steps I have taken:**

- Installed mz2geohash library into QGIS 3.10 python environment using pip
- Verified functionality of mz2geohash library in QGIS 3.10 python environment
  [image]
- Integrated suggested changes in Comments 1 & 2 from Gabriel De Luca and jbalk
  (removal of extraneous parentheses)
- <del>Recast ft_tup as an array using the QGIS array() function</del>
- Removed empty initialization of tuple since it is immutable and makes no sense, as per Gabriel De Luca and ThingumaBob.
- Added ft_array to create an empty array element
- Added ft_array.append(ft_lon) and ft_array.append(ft_lat) to add values to ft_array
- aliased mz2geohash.encode as geohash32
- Verified that these steps work stepwise in the Python terminal
  [image]

**What I'm doing with my code:**
<del>ft_tup is establishing an empty tuple</del>
ft_centroid is getting the centroid as a geometry object for the current feature
ft_lon is returning the X value of the centroid projected into WGS84
ft_lat is returning the Y value of the centroid projected into WGS84
ft_array is establishing an empty array to hold the results of ft_lon,ft_lat
ft_array.append(ft_lon) is inserting the x value into position 0 of the array
ft_array.append(ft_lat) is inserting the y value into position 1 of the array
geohash32 is created as an alias for mz2geohash.encode
return geohash32(ft_array) is supposed to give the encoded geohash

**What QGIS has to say about my code:**

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import mz2geohash 

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def geohash32(value,feature,parent):
    ft_centroid = centroid($geometry) 
    ft_lon = x(transform(ft_centroid),layer_property(@layer_id,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) 
    ft_lat = y(transform(ft_centroid),layer_property(@layer_id,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) 
    ft_array = [] 
    ft_array.append(ft_lon) 
    ft_array.append(ft_lat) 
    geohash32 = mz2geohash.encode 
    return geohash32(ft_array)


traceback.print_exception() failed

Python version:


QGIS version:
3.10.0-A Coruña 'A Coruña', 6ffa89eb3e

Python path:
```

Individually, each line from the above works when tested in the python console outside of QGIS, or when each line is tested in the Field Calculator (with variables substituted for actual values).
**Examples:**

```
ft_centroid  
centroid($geometry) = <geometry: Point>  
ft_lon  
x(transform(centroid($geometry),layer_property(@layer_id,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) = -82.83264665692754  
ft_lat  
y(transform(centroid($geometry),layer_property(@layer_id,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) = 42.61281133650196
```

**Why do I want this?**
I strongly desire the ability for QGIS to create human-readable spatially-derived interoperable/standardized GUIDs.

See my issue here:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31327

**What will I do with the fixed code?**
Open a PR to have this moved to core so everyone can use it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Seen only from the point of view of QGIS expressions, I would say that the correct way is:`x( transform( ft_centroid, layer_property( @layer_id, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))` and `y( transform( ft_centroid, layer_property( @layer_id, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))`.  _Individually, each line from the above works_ surprises me because it seems that they have a parenthesis left over.

Comment: remove the parenthesis after both instances of ft_centroid so it's like x(transform(ft_centroid,layer_prop...

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I've integrated the changes you've suggested, as well as tried to recast ft_tup as an array (which works as a single line in the Field Calculator), but I still can't get the code to validate and run.

Comment: for [EPSG:4326](http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/9.8.4/4326) shouldn't x be lat (the first axis)?

Comment: I don't know if `ft_tup = ()` is the way to initialize an empty array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca it's the way to create an empty *tuple*; a tuple, however, is immutable, so it doesn't make sense to initialize it empty. It seems the `encode` function accepts either a *tuple* (!= *array*), or two separate values. Maybe try to fulfill that explicitly.

Comment: Verified that I have the variables correctly mapped between Lat/Lon and X/Y as per nmtoken; removed empty initialization of tuple as per Gabriel De Luca and ThingumaBob.

Comment: I think that you cannot use expressions as if they were functions in pyqgis, but you can use `QgsExpression()` functions instead. That is all I could investigate, it totally escapes my current knowledge.

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that this is only suitable for a small subset of SQL operators, which I do not believe would be compatible with what I'm doing above.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#expressions-with-features

An example given in the QGIS Developer Cookbook appears to show a fairly complex expression with multiple functions that I would assume evaluates successfully. 

There must be something wrong with how I've written my above code.

Comment: It would appear that the proper way to do what I want is to use pyqgis functions. I've begun restructuring the function around the pyqgis functions and expressions, but am having difficulty trying to construct the proper syntax.

Comment: After many mistakes, but many more tests, I found two functions that may not be elegant but both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression can be introduced, as a string, as an argument of the `QgsExpression()` function.
Then, it must be evaluated in the context in which the `geohash()` function is called.

The `$geometry` expression seems to be evaluating well within the function, but no. The output is shown correctly in the preview, but when executed it returns a null value, to which the encode function returns an error.

I was able to access the geometry through the `row_number` variable. I disarmed the whole expression in parts so that it is a little less confusing.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import mz2geohash 

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def geohash32_noargs(feature, parent, context):

    geometry_expression = r"geometry( get_feature_by_id( '" +  context.variable( 'layer_id' ) + r"' , " + str(context.variable( 'row_number' )) + r"))"
    centroid_expression = r"centroid( " + geometry_expression + r")"
    layerCRS_expression = r"layer_property( '" + context.variable( 'layer_id' ) + r"' , 'crs')"
    transform_expression = r"transform( " + centroid_expression + r", " + layerCRS_expression + r", 'EPSG:4326')"

    x_expression = QgsExpression('x( ' + transform_expression + ')')
    x_value = x_expression.evaluate(context)

    y_expression = QgsExpression('y( ' + transform_expression + ')')
    y_value = y_expression.evaluate(context)

    value = (x_value, y_value)
    return mz2geohash.encode(value)
```

Finally, create a new string data type field and populate it with the `geohash32_noargs()` expression.

---

I am absolutely sure that the transformation, obtaining the centroid, and obtaining its coordinates, can be performed from functions of the imported libraries, without evaluating them as an expression (but I still wouldn't know how to do it). However, learning to evaluate expressions within the function is valid.

---

Another option (seems better to me) would be to define the `geohash32()` function with two parameters:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import mz2geohash 

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def geohash32(x_value, y_value, feature, parent):
    """
    Encodes a ( lon , lat ) pair to a GeoHash,
    requires the <a href="https://github.com/jason-h-simplifi/mapzen-geohash">mz2geohash package</a> installed...
    <br>
    <h2>Example usage:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>geohash32( -58.4 , -34.6 ) -> '69y7pj62mkeb'</li> 
        <li>geohash32( "lon" , "lat" ) ->  a  base 32 GeoHash string </li>
    </ul>
    """
    value = (x_value, y_value)
    return mz2geohash.encode(value)
```

And call it from the expression builder with the proper arguments:

```
geohash32( 
  x( transform( 
    centroid( $geometry),
    layer_property( @layer_id, 'crs'),
    'EPSG:4326')), 
  y( transform( 
    centroid( $geometry),
    layer_property( @layer_id, 'crs'),
    'EPSG:4326')))
```

---

I'm sorry if I'm confusing functions with objects, methods or classes. Take this answer as a beginner's effort.

Comment: This looks amazing! I can't thank you enough for your effort. Please allow me a few days to read this over, test it out, and try implementing it. Once I do, I'll follow back up here with you.

Comment: @Saijin_Naib You are welcome. I have just added a description for the `geohash32()` function.

Comment: The top function doesn't seem to work when I'm computing the geohash32 using the geohash32_noargs() expression. It throws this error: An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: The bottom function works great as you've set it up, however, I'm noticing an offset/shit in the geohash values when computed this way versus computing them manually using Lat Lon Tools and pre-derived line segment centroids. The difference isn't huge, but it is noticeable.

For instance: manual geohash dr8v30ht6uxy vs computed geohash dr8v30ht7h8k

Comment: Manually computing the geohash32 using the python terminal and mz2geohash with the derived X/Y values from the pre-derived line segment centroids yields results consistent with Lat Lon Tools, not the computed values from your expression. Odd...

Comment: I have that function working. Have you tried to debug it returning the expressions strings? About the geohash32 funtion, it just run the mz2geohash function with the arguments given. Maybe are you giving it different arguments or I don't know what is the function used in Lat Lon Tools.

Comment: If you call the geohash32 function with numerical arguments and the mz32geohash function with the same arguments, they must return the same result. About the geohash_noargs function, if the expression is well formed all you need to do is check the context: you need to run it from an active layer, with a defined CRS, with geometries in their features.